# javafx how to test image equality?

Tags: java, image, javafx, equality

```
for (int i = 0; i < image1Width; i++)
{
  for (int j = 0; j < image1Height; j++)
  {
    if (image1.getPixelReader().getColor(i, j) != image2.getPixelReader().getColor(i, j)) return false;
  }
}
```

This is what I have at the moment.  I pass the function two Images (javafx.scene.image.Image).  This means that this should never return false when the images are the same.  Unfortunately, this returns false when I pass it the same image.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need

```
if (!image1.getPixelReader().getColor(i, j).equals(image2.getPixelReader().getColor(i, j))) return false;
```

or

```
if (image1.getPixelReader().getArgb(i, j) != image2.getPixelReader().getArgb(i, j)) return false;
```

The second version may be faster.

Comment: Thank you very much.  This took care of the problem.  Interesting that comparing colors doesn't do the job.

Comment: It should work by comparing colors, as long as you use the correct test for equality.

Comment: Right, I see that.  ==/!= compares values right? Shouldn't getColor() return a value that can be compared against the same color?  I'm just interested in why ==/!= isn't sufficient.

Comment: No, `==` when used on a reference type (Color is a reference type, the int is a primitive type) compares references. You should use `.equals(...)` when comparing reference types, unless you have good reason not to.

Answer (score 0):

For someone who just want to copy and paste this ready to use method

```
private boolean isImageEqual(Image firstImage, Image secondImage){
    // Prevent `NullPointerException`
    if(firstImage != null && secondImage == null) return false;
    if(firstImage == null) return secondImage == null;

    // Compare images size
    if(firstImage.getWidth() != secondImage.getWidth()) return false;
    if(firstImage.getHeight() != secondImage.getHeight()) return false;

    // Compare images color
    for(int x = 0; x < firstImage.getWidth(); x++){
        for(int y = 0; y < firstImage.getHeight(); y++){
            int firstArgb = firstImage.getPixelReader().getArgb(x, y);
            int secondArgb = secondImage.getPixelReader().getArgb(x, y);

            if(firstArgb != secondArgb) return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```